# How to support ui for different medias like iphones,tablets,android phones

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I am trying to develop and fixing the issues for application which has to be support for different medias like iPhones,tablets,android phones.

In our application we are using foundation css framework to support different media.

I tried by googling but I have got some media related tags only.

Can anybody give me any example which supports as mentioned above using foundation css or any other way.So I can move forward.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by different medias?

Answer (score 0):

I know there are some technologies that enables you to use HTML, CSS and Javascript to develop native iPhone,android,Tablet,iPad apps. I've identified a few:

[Ansca Mobile](http://coronalabs.com/)

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)

[Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Gideros](http://giderosmobile.com/), it is written in Lua, open source and easy to use.